# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, xcode, gcc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int palindrome(char str1[], int n){
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<=(n/2)-1 ;i++){
        if(str1[i]!=str1[n-1-i]){
            result = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void copyArrayChar(char *src, char *dest,int startSrc, int size){
    for(int i=0; i<=size-1; i++){
        src[startSrc + i] = dest[i];
    }
}

int patternj(char str1[], int n){
    int result = 0;
    int check;
    check = palindrome(str1, n);
    if(n==1||n==0){
        result = 1;
    } else if(check == 1){
        char strL[n/2], strR[n/2];
        copyArrayChar(str1, strL, 0, n/2);
        copyArrayChar(str1, strR, (n/2)+1, n/2);
        result+= patternj(strL,n/2) + patternj(strR, n/2);
    }
    return result;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string str[100000];
    int strLength[100000], result[100000];
    char str1[100000][100000];
    int ni;
    cin >> ni;
    for(int i=0;i<=ni-1;i++){
        getline(cin,str[i]);
        strLength[i] = (int) str[i].length();
        str[i].copy(str1[i],strLength[i],0);
        result[i]= patternj(str1[i], strLength[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, so I've written this code to check for patternj strings but for some reason it gives me an error with this name "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8)". I don't quite understand why this is happening.

Comment: `str1` is `100000 * 100000 = 10,000,000,000` (approx 9.5Gb) `char`s and is exceeding default stack limit of about 1Mb.

Comment: `char strL[n/2], strR[n/2];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime variable.  Instead use `std::vector<char>`, and possibly `std::string`, since what you have is an array of `char`.  Second --  `string str[100000]; int strLength[100000], result[100000]; char str1[100000][100000];` -- You need to think up a better strategy than blindly declaring these gigantic arrays up front like this.  No good C++ programmer would ever write code like this. 
 This is where `std::vector` could have been used.